# Is there a way to check for turtles in a n patch radius of a turtle?

Tags: netlogo

I want to make a drive-thru simulator where the cars automatically leave some space in between them and the car in front of them. Right now I am able to make sure that they don't move right next to each other by checking to see if the neighboring patches have another car on them. The trouble is, this still lets them overlap a little bit. How can I use NetLogo to make sure that if another car is in a car's 4 patch radius, the car doesn't move?

I want my cars to move east, then south, then east, then north, and then disappear. For this reason, my code looks like this thus far:

```
to move
  ask turtles
  [
    if pycor > 12 and pxcor < -10 [
      set heading 90 ; set the starting heading
      if not any? turtles-on neighbors
      [
        if not (count turtles-on patches with [pxcor = -10] > 5) or pxcor != -14 [forward 1]
      ]
    ]
    if pycor > -11 and count turtles-on patches with [pxcor < -8] < 13
    [
      if (pxcor = -10  and pycor < 15)  or (pxcor = -14)
      [
        set heading 180 ; start moving downwards
        if not any? turtles-on neighbors
        [
          if not (count turtles-on patches with [pycor = -11] > 5) or pycor != -8 [forward 1]
          if num-dto = 2
          [
            if count turtles-on patches with [pxcor = -10] > count turtles-on patches with [pxcor = -14] and pxcor = -10
            [
              set heading 270
              forward 4
              set heading 180
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
    if pycor = -11 and pxcor < 13 [
      set heading 90 ; start moving to the right
      if not any? turtles-on neighbors
      [
        if not (count turtles-on patches with [pxcor = 13] > 5) or pxcor != 12 [forward 1]
      ]
    ]
    if pxcor = 13 and pycor < 12 [
       ; start moving up
      if not any? turtles-on neighbors [set heading 0 forward 1]
    ]
     ;if pxcor > 12 and pycor > 11 [die]
  ]
end
```

I would really like it if there was a cleaner way to do this. Thanks for your help, I am very new to programming in NetLogo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like [`in-radius`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-radius) or, more likely so that your turtles check only in front of them, [`in-cone`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-cone). Both of these check for some agents within a distance, `in-cone` adds a 'cone' of vision defined by degrees.

For example:

```
turtles-own [ speed ]

to setup
  ca
  ask patch -10 -10 [
    sprout 1 [
      set heading 0
      repeat 4 [
        repeat 20 [ 
          set pcolor grey
          fd 1 
          if random-float 1 < 0.15 [
            hatch 1 [
              set heading [heading] of myself
              set speed 0.25 + random-float 0.5
              set color 102 + ( speed * 5 )
            ]
          ]
        ]
        rt 90
      ]
      die
    ]
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    if not any? other turtles in-cone 4 90 [
      ifelse [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black [
        rt 90
        set xcor pxcor
        set ycor pycor
      ] [     
        fd speed
      ]
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

I will also mention that you say your turtles `overlap`- I just want to point out that although their images may overlap (if the turtle shape is larger than the patch size, for example), `turtles` actually only occupy a single point (their `xcor` and `ycor` value). For aesthetic purposes the overlap may be important, but for the purposes of your modelling it may not be.

Comment: Thank you so much! That is super helpful, you told me exactly what I needed to know.